What is this episode about tiny people/humans?
I'm looking for a TV show where a man who creates miniatures wakes up one day to discover that there are two tiny human characters alive. Then a society starts to develop out of tiny humans that engages in a rebellion at some point and the man ends up killing them. The episode, far from the fantastic fact of the tiny humans is more centred on the drama of the guy's interactions with them, playing to be god.
I think the country of origin is the United States, it was in English and in color. I don't remember the release date, I watched it in the early 2000's.
(Actually, I am looking for the title to make a gift to a friend...so, your help would be very much appreciated!)

I think this story has been re-told a number of times with slightly different details, the one that stands out in my mind is the Twilight Zone episode "The Little People"
The Simpsons also did a parody of this story in Tree House of Horror VII

Any sense of how tiny they were?  I thought of "Darby O'Gill and the Little People".  There is a rebellion, but nobody gets killed.  Or maybe "Dr. Cyclops", a mad scientist who miniaturizes things and who does kill one small person, but no society.

I dont know the release date, I watched it in the early 2000's... I am sure it is not an episode, it is a movie... The little humans, I assume they were the size of a pinky. Yes, they started to claim for things, rights as I can recall... and the man killed them in an outbreak of rage. I have tried to put a face to the actor, but I cant... The movie, far from the fantastic fact of the tiny humans is more centred on the drama of the guy playing to be God... Voilà! Your questions may trigger my memories, so go ahead and ask ;) THANK YOU ALL!

I remember a similar scene in an episode from Futurama where Bender has a civilization on his back. But unfortunately it does not match.

Thanks, Franz! I have also searched with every single criteria I could think of with no luck... Most of the time the search matches some episodes but no movie.

Are you thinking of The Indian in the Cupboard by any chance?

Unfortunately, it is not The Indian In The Cupboard, Adam. Thanks!

The Collector's The Minituarist is quite close. It aired in 2004 and was about a dollhouse maker whose wish is granted when 2 of his miniature humans (a man and a woman) come alive. They build a society, he plays God and it doesn't end well. But again, this was an episode. You can find it (in a rather zoomed-in version) here.

@Walt And there we go... I used the reference that my friend gave me... He was so sure it was a movie! Had to have the evidence that Walt gave me to convince him. Indeed this is the right material. THANK YOU so much, Walt!!! Now, he would like to have the full series :)  Is there some DVD release you know about?

I am very sorry for the inaccurate information I provided at the beginning, guys! I really appreciate your help, time and attention.

As confirmed in the comments, this is an episode of The Collector from 2004 called The Miniaturist about a dollhouse maker whose wish is granted when two of his miniatures (a man and a woman) come alive and build a society. From TV.com:

Morgan's client is Harvey Fenderman, who made a deal with the Devil to be able to create miniature landscapes and people. The Devil has caused Fenderman to recreate the village where Morgan and Katrina lived to cause pain for Morgan and sidetrack Morgan and Fenderman from finding Fenderman's redemption. Things get disturbing when Morgan finds that the Devil has given Fenderman the power to create living miniatures. One of the miniatures looks exactly like Katrina.


